# Is it considered API if I have css attributes called through javascript?

Tags: html, javascript, css, api

I am making a website for a school project, I don't know exactly what API is but from what little I know, is that it is the integration of multiple sources to give the user an outcome?

If that is the case, would using some attributes in js such as using query selector to manipulate some css stuff be considered API.

If not then how can I incorporate this in my website?

We are required to have non-core API.

Comment: The requirements can only be reliably explained by your school, in particular what they mean by "non-core" API. It could be that querySelector() counts, it could be that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, an API is an application programming interface. Think of it as a way for software to communicate with other software.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API

As an example, look at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page/en

For a basic explanation of what an API is and does see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZvSYJDk-us

You should ask your teacher what he wants you to do.